# Wrap words in paragraph with span, keep nested links functioning

Tags: jquery, split, html

How might I wrap every word in a paragraph with a span while keeping any nested links functioning? Using the code below from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10442959/1525810) I get close, but splitting on whitespace inserts a span between the `a` and the `href` resulting in something like this:

```
<p><span><a< span> <span>href="#"&gt;this</span></a<></span></p>
```

which obviously renders the link unusable.

```
$('p').each(function() {

var text = $(this).html().split(/\s+/),//split on space
    len = text.length,
    result = []; 

for( var i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
    result[i] = '<span>' + text[i] + '</span>';
}
$(this).html(result.join(' '));
});
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/psflannery/JRF2z/27/) which perhaps better illustrates my point. Thanks!

Comment: I think you'd be better using .text() and not .html()

Comment: You can use [regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124297/how-to-parse-for-a-word-in-text-in-javascript), but I think you may end up with a lot of complexity that may not be necessary. Making a word parser could work and be built to detect `<` tokens and move to the character after the next `>`, although that could also be problematic. I think the result then would be something like a recursive node walker, which may also be messy. Hmm.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - I take it it's something along these lines: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/A6PDb/ Also, I imagine someone, somewhere, has handled this before...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you don't want to randomly be inserting `"<span>"` tags *inside* of other tags. A resulting html like: `<img <span>src="blahblah"</span>>` is going to be an issue, were you ever to get one.

You can use a regex to match out the tags in the HTML and only add `<span>` tags to everything else. Probably not perfect, but something like:

```
$('p').each(function() {

    var tagRE = /([^<]*)(<(?:\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^>'\"]*)*>)([^<]*)/g,
        match,
        result = [],
        i = 0;

    while(match = tagRE.exec($(this).html())) {
        var text1 = match[1].split(/\s+/),
            len1 = text1.length;

        var text2 = match[3].split(/\s+/),
            len2 = text2.length;

        for(var tIdx = 0; tIdx < len1; tIdx++ )
            result[i++] = '<span>' + text1[tIdx] + '</span>';           

        result[i++] = match[2];

        for(var tIdx = 0; tIdx < len2; tIdx++ )
            result[i++] = '<span>' + text2[tIdx] + '</span>';          
    }

    $(this).html(result.join(' '));

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5wabK/

It's probably a little inefficient but I had to use a group at the beginning and the end in order to capture everything before the first tag and after the last one.

Comment: Cleaned up example, also shows the effect with css: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/5wabK/1/

Comment: I guess technically as well, it envelopes punctuation like `text.`.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks, and yes it does technically envelop punctuation. You could change the split-and-concatenate routine with a `replace()` call and make a regex that avoids punctuation, but you will have to define what is and isn't considered punctuation. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...